# Python Django: Getting None Values from empty modelform field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have Django 2.0 running and I am getting a None Value from an empty form field. I think this field should deliver an empty string:

Model:

```
class FooterMenu(models.Model):
    ...
    text_en = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Menüpunkt (en)", max_length=100, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

Modelform:

```
class Meta:
        model = FooterMenu
        exclude = ('position', 'column')
```

View

```
...
form1 = FooterForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
print(form1.cleaned_data['text_en'])
```

Stdout:

```
None
```

Can anybody shed some light why this is happening?

Maybe I have set stupid values in the model definition?

Comment: Your model field has null=True. You shouldn't use that on a charfield.

Comment: Your comment was spot on. That was the cause of my issue.